# extracting child href to BeautifulSoup list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href, urllib2

I am learning python and using BeautifulSoup to crawl some webpages. What I am looking to do is find child 'a' of the first 'td', extract the href and add it to the list. How and where can I add the href's to the cell text?

```
import urllib2

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def listify(table):
    """Convert an html table to a nested list""" 
    result = []
    rows = table.findAll('tr')
    for row in rows:
        result.append([])
        cols = row.findAll('td')
        for col in cols:
            strings = [_string.encode('utf8') for _string in col.findAll(text=True)]
            text = ''.join(strings)
            result[-1].append(text)
    return result
```

Comment: `cols[1].find('a')['href']` should do the trick

Comment: Any reason you are not using BeautifulSoup 4 instead of 3?

Comment: good call on bs4. I downloaded both but installed 3. Now using 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Find the first `td`: Use `row.find('td')` instead; it'll return the first match
- Find child `a`, again, use `.find('a')` to find the first.
- Elements act like a python `dict`, use item access to get element attributes such as `href`.

Together, that makes:

```
cell = row.find('td')
link = cell.find('a') if cell else None
if link is not None and 'href' in link:
    result[-1].append(link['href'])
```